# Drag and Drop в jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Когда меняю элементы местами, они с левой стороны монитора "прилетают" в Chrome.

```
$('#Id').sortable({
    handle  : '.handler',
            revert  : 'true',
    items   : 'li',
    axis    : 'y',
});
```

Comment: наверняка проблемы в верстке, видно элементы с float и где-то в контейнере есть 1-2 лишних пикселя, вот они сначала хотят вмоститься туда, но когда им не хватает места становятся как надо

Comment: А как понять такое поведение: в Огнелисе7 все нормально, а в остальных стежит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было простым ,если axis: 'X' то элемент "прилетал" с 'Y',и наоборот.
Нужно было просто убрать revert : 'true',revert - возвращает элемент на место ,вот он и не сходился.